# DIV coding not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use div to hide areas based on date/time. From what I can see, what I have should work. Can somebody take a look at it and let me know where I'm off?

I'm using HHMMSS so that I can keep testing it as I make changes, but the actual coding will only need YYYYMMDD.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <style>
        .container {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>

    THIS IS A TEST SCRIPT<br />

    <div class=".container" id="one" data-hideafter="20150430 091400")
    <p>content one goes here</p>
    hi

    </div>

    hi there

    <div class=".container" id="two" data-hideafter="20150430 091430")
    <p>content two goes here</p>

    </div>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            var currentDate = newDate();

            $('.container').each(function() {
                if ($(this).data-hideafter) < currentDate)
                $(this).show();
            }
            }
        })();
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

There's a lot of other coding that will eventually go between the divs, but it's mostly tables.

Thanks,
BAC

Comment: What is this `<div class=".container" id="one" data-hideafter="20150430 091400")` supposed to do???

Comment: It looks like a misprint.

Comment: `".container"` is not a valid class name. `".container"`  matches the class `"container"` just like `"#foo"` matches an element with `id="foo"`

Comment: Well your only grabbing a snapshot of the time with var currentDate = newDate(); , you would want to drop a timeout on that to update it frequently if you want this stuff to happen on the fly, not just when you load.

Comment: Should the ".container" hold the id information as well? I'm not sure how to do that if I need to add that to the [  .container {   display:  none; } area.

Comment: Happening on load only would be fine. As I said, the final will only need to activate on date, not time of day.

Comment: `$(this).data-hideafter` is also invalid. It is interpreted as `$(this).data - hideafter` (minus sign). Should be `$(this).data('hideafter')`. Also, you compare a String and a Date, can't work. `newDate()` is another bug (newDate is undefined), should be `new Date()`. Ouch! You bet your code is "not working as intended"  :)

Comment: @Halcyon `.container` is a valid [class](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes) name. However, the dot must be escaped in the [class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#class-html): `.\.container`.

Comment: @Oriol you're right that `\.container` is a valid classname but `.container` is an invalid classname. As far as I know HTML does no validation on the class property. For the CSS spec see: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the HTML you have is not valid. So, I presume something went wrong when posting the question. Try using the following HTML and JavaScript to *hide* container `foo` (container `bar` will be hidden tomorrow):

```
<div class="container" id="foo" data-hide-after="2015-04-29">Foo</div>
<div class="container" id="bar" data-hide-after="2015-04-30">Bar</div>
<div class="container" id="baz" data-hide-after="2015-05-01">Baz</div>
```

Note that I've changed the format of the date here so that it can be parsed. Also, I renamed the data attribute to `data-hide-after`.

```
$(function() {
    var currentDate = new Date();

    $('.container').each(function() {
        var hideAfter = new Date($(this).data('hide-after'));
        if (currentDate > hideAfter) {
           $(this).hide();
        }
    });
})();
```

Note in the JavaScript above that I'm checking whether the current date is **after** the `hide-after` date. If so, the container should be *hidden*.

**P.S.**
You can now remove this:

```
.container {
    display: none;
}
```

#### Update

If you want to support hide-after and show-after at the same time, you could do something like this:

```
<div class="container" id="foo" data-hide-after="2015-05-01T10:00:00">Foo</div>
<div class="container" id="bar" data-hide-after="2015-05-01T20:00:00">Bar</div>
<div class="container" id="baz" data-hide-after="2015-05-02">Baz</div>
<div class="container" id="qux" data-show-after="2015-05-01">Qux</div>
```

Note that the last container has a `data-show-after` element.

```
$(function() {
    // first hide all show-after containers, since we only need to show them after the specified date.
    $('div[data-show-after]').hide();

    var currentDate = new Date();

    $('.container').each(function() {
        var hideAfter = $(this).data('hide-after');
        var showAfter = $(this).data('show-after');

        if (hideAfter) {
            var parsedHideAfter = new Date(hideAfter);
            if (currentDate > parsedHideAfter) {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        }

        if (showAfter) {
            var parsedShowAfter = new Date(showAfter);
            if (currentDate > parsedShowAfter) {
                $(this).show();
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Thanks newmediafreak, that seems to work OK. For testing, it's a little slow just using date... can I add HH:MM:SS to the hide after times to make it cycle every minute in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format?

Comment: @BruceChecca Yeah, that will definitely work. Instead of `2015-04-30` just add `2015-04-30 20:30:10` as `data-hide-after`, so that you can check it every second.

Comment: Found that I had to modify the format to YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS to get it to work. It wouldn't with the space as a separator.   Also used your function as a basis to create a "show after" function... but can't get both to work in the same page. Both work in JSFiddle just fine, just not together....

Comment: @BruceChecca I've updated my answer. I've added support for both hide-after as well as show-after at the same time. Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

access data through data attribute:

```
$(this).data("hideafter");
```

and you will need to parse the result to be Date:

```
new Date($(this).data("hideafter"))
```

Full code:

```
$(function() {
   var currentDate = new Date();

   $('.container').each(function() {

     d = $(this).data("hideafter");
     year = d.substring(0, 4);
     month = parseInt(d.substring(4, 6)) - 1;  // Subtruct 1 here as month start from zero in javascript date object
     day = d.substring(6, 8);
     hour = d.substring(9, 11);  
     minutes = d.substring(11, 13);    
     second = d.substring(13, 15);
     element_date = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minutes, second); 
     if (element_date < currentDate){
       $(this).show();
      }
   });

})();
```

Also you have a problem with your class container it show

```
class=".container"  // wrong
class="container"   // correct
```

Comment: `new Date($(this).data("hideafter"))` doesn't work. `"20150430 091400"` is not a valid date format.

Comment: What am I missing Jeremy?

Comment: @BruceChecca i make it work for your code, although date should be in better format to be able for easy parsing.

Comment: Absolutely. The data-hideafter should be at a proper Date format : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp